# Piping video device over SSH or tcptunnel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ssh, video-capture

I want to attach an analog camera to an old linux computer and directly pipe the /dev/video0 to another computer, where I can use it as a device again (so /dev/video0 should go to /dev/remote0, for example)

(Reason for doing this is that the computer does not have enough power to encode the video)

Is that possible? I've seen people can pipe the data directly from the device over ssh into mplayer, but I need to have some sort of reference point for Zoneminder.

- Edit: As Phil Hannent said: SSH would probably also be too resource intensive for the hardware as it has to encrypt the data it sends. So is this also possible over a program like tcptunnel?
- Edit2: On the Unix & Linux stackexchange site I found a question that uses this for piping over ssh: `ssh localhost dd if=/dev/video0 | mplayer tv://device=/dev/stdin` can that be done over tcptunnel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/).

```
cat /dev/video0 | nc -l 1234
```

This will open a server on one host listening on port `1234` and sending uncompressed and unencrypted data from `/dev/video0` to any client that connects. You can receive the data on other host by invoking:

```
nc videohost 1234 | mplayer tv://device=/dev/stdin
```

where `videohost` is the host sending data from `/dev/video0`.

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to pipe the data into a /dev/file first, and then separately opening it in mplayer?

Comment: I think creating device would be too complicated, but if you need something file-like you could try a fifo pipe (`mknod /tmp/videofifo p`) write the stream to it and pipe it's contents to `mplayer` using `cat`. Not sure how the pipe would behave if you don't read the data from it though.

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight. Very interested to see how it'll turn out!

Comment: I'd also like to point out ipusb: it probably works even better than this. It lets you mount a usb device over the network.

Comment: "nc videohost 1234 | mplayer tv://device=/dev/stdin" output error "Playing tv://device=/dev/stdin.
The filename option must be an integer: dev/stdin
Struct tv, field filename parsing error: dev/stdin". I think this problem in my webcam or in my mplayer. "nc videohost 1234 | vlc - " work for me.

Comment: Tried this - cat: /dev/video0: Invalid argument

Comment: @Ryan, try netcat (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534994/dev-video0-invalid-argument)

Answer (score 4):

The netcat solution didn't work for me. It either shows a pipe error, or `cat` reporting `Invalid input`.

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
ssh user@host "ffmpeg  -r 14 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f matroska -" | mplayer - -idle
```

This has the benefit of it being encoded, so you save bandwidth as a bonus.

---

Combine with [tee](https://superuser.com/questions/1356841/what-is-the-purpose-of-tee) and you can watch and record at the same time:

```
ssh user@host "ffmpeg  -r 14 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f matroska -" | tee $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)_recording.mkv | mplayer - -idle
```

This will open mplayer for live streaming and save it to a file containing the current datetime at the same time (example filename: `2018-11-22_01-22-10_recording.mkv`).

---

Replace `-f matroska` with `-f avi` to use the more compressed avi format. This will save a lot of CPU resources on the source and a lot of bandwidth for a more lag free experience.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously advise you against this.  I recently tried streaming avi videos over an ssh:// file access and its painful.  You have to remember that the video is being encrypted and then decrypted during this process.

If your computer cannot handle compressing the stream then it certainly will not be able to handle encrypting it.

Really you want to just have a tcp tunnel the raw data:

http://www.vakuumverpackt.de/tcptunnel/

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. But how would you pipe device data over this?