# What is the purpose of 'tee'?

Tags: shell, tee

All the usages of [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) I ever saw were such:

```
 do_something | tee -a logfile
```

Or:

```
do_something_else | tee logfile
```

Is `tee` invented for those that don't know you can do the same with shell pipe redirections? Such as:

```
do_something >> logfile
```

Or:

```
do_something_else > logfile
```

It's practically the same and it takes less keyboard hits to type out. What  hidden  features am I not seeing in `tee`?

Comment: How was this not answered by the very first line of the man page *"...and write to standard output and files"*? The answers are interesting, but broadly talking about how pipes are useful just reinforces how this Q seems *too broad,* and should perhaps have been closed.

Comment: @Xen2050 A question cannot be blamed for a too-broad answer. The question is very specific, as is the current [highest rated answer](https://superuser.com/a/1356843/179350).

Comment: @JonBentley the question doesn't sound like *"a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"* (as the close dialog reads). It does sound like this: *"if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format."* (Source: the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions))

Comment: @Xen2050 Are we reading the same question? It seems highly specific to me - what is the difference between tee and pipes? It has been adequately answered using two sentences. Far from an entire book. The fact that some answers *choose* to go off on a tangent has nothing to do with the scope of the question.

Comment: @JonBentley: Are we reading the same question?  R Moog kind-of sort-of *implies* a fairly well focused question — what is the difference between `tee` *and **I/O redirection**?*  The fact that it says “shell ***pipe** redirections* such as `>` and `>>`” is not a point in its favor, and is an argument for closing as unclear.  But it actually asks multiple questions: “What is the purpose of `tee`?”, “Is `tee` invented for those that don’t know you can do the same with shell pipe redirections?” and “What hidden features am I not seeing in ``tee``?”.  At least two of those questions are too broad.

Comment: @G-Man You have to go out of your way to make that interpretation. It is obvious that the fundamental

Comment: I “have to go out of [my] way to make that interpretation”?  Huh? I’m ***quoting!***

Answer (score 253):

What you don't see is that `do_something | tee -a logfile` puts the output into `logfile` **and** to stdout, while `do_something >> logfile` puts it **only** into the logfile.

The purpose of `tee` is to produce a one input, multiple output scenario - just like in a 'T' crossing.

**EDIT**

There have been comments around how `tee` enables more seemless use of `sudo`. This is beside the point: `cat`, `dd` or maybe better `buffer` provide this possibility with better performance, if you don't need the multiple outputs. Use `tee` for what it is designed, not for what it "can also do"

Comment: Multiple output is the key. `tee` can even take multiple arguments and write to many files at once.

Comment: I would call it a tee *pipe fitting*, not a crossing (as in a road intersection?) Stuff comes in one way and goes out both ways.

Comment: Even after you said "'T' crossing" it didn't immediately occur to me that the command literally spells it out

Comment: Oh it was meant to be like a T crossing? I used to assume it was a reference to golf tee.

Comment: Also, you can't use `sudo` when redirecting to a file you don't have permissions for, while you can always use `sudo` for `tee`.

Comment: How would I use `cat` in a straightforward way instead of `tee` in e.g. `echo /var/work/core.%p | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`? `echo /var/work/core.%p | sudo cat > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` doesn't work, because the redirect is processed by the non-sudo shell. As for `dd`, `echo /var/work/core.%p | sudo dd of=/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` works, but `dd` is  often an overpowered tool capable of doing great damage, especially under `sudo`.  As for `buffer`, its not installed by default in any of the RedHat- or Ubuntu-based distros I have to hand (or MacOS)...

Comment: ... `echo /var/work/core.%p | sudo sh -c 'cat > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'`works, though I think that extra `sh -c` is hardly elegant

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `echo /var/work/core.%p | sudo /bin/cat > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` works fine - your command line uses the shell-internal version of cat (but not the shell-internal version of tee). In addition to that, `sudo tee` and `sudo dd` have exactly the same potential to destruct. Un a new Ubuntu, `audo apt install buffer` is one of the "must do" customizations, as `sudo buffer` can work wonders, if you e.g. write  an ffmpeg log to a disk. Most importantly, my point was, that the `sudo`use of `tee` is not what makes it special - the 1:n relation between in and out is.

Comment: @EugenRieck I do get your point about about the 1:n relation between in:out being the primary function.  However, neither the builtin `cat` nor `/bin/cat` work for me in this situation.  It doesn't matter where `cat` comes from - the `>` will still be handled by the top level (non-sudo) shell. The advantage of `tee` over `cat` in this situation is that it allows the output file to be passed as a command-line param (and not a redirect).  `dd` is certainly a viable option, though I'd still favour `tee` for this

Comment: @EugenRieck What shell has `cat` and `tee` as builtins? And what version of `sudo` can run shell builtins?

Comment: @wjandrea BASH on Ubuntu 18.04 has `cat` but not `tee` according to man 7 `bash-builtins`

Comment: @Eugen Where in [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html) does it say that?

Comment: @EugenRieck using `sudo cat > ...` does _not_ work, and it _cannot_ work unless your shell (the thing parsing the command line) has permission to write to the file. The `> ...` is parsed by the shell, it is _not_ given to the application as an argument. It has nothing to do with being a builtin.

Answer (score 123):

## `Tee` is not useless

Maybe you knew that anyway? If not, read on! Or if you know how it works, but aren't sure *why* it exists, skip to the end to see how it fit in the with the Unix philosophy.

## What *is* the purpose of `tee`?

At its simplest, it takes data on standard input and writes that to standard output and one (or more) files. It has been likened to a [plumbing tee piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_plumbing_fitting#Tee) in the way it splits one input into two outputs (and two directions).

### Examples

Let's take your first example:

```
do_something | tee -a logfile
```

This takes the output of `do_something` and appends it to logfile, while also displaying it to the user. In fact, the [Wikipedia page on `tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) has this as the second example:

> To view and append the output from a command to an existing file:
>
> ```
>   lint program.c | tee -a program.lint
> ```
>
> This displays the standard output of the lint program.c command at the computer and at the same time appends a copy of it to the end of the program.lint file. If the program.lint file does not exist, it is created.

The very next example has another use: *escalation of permissions*:

> To allow escalation of permissions:
>
> ```
> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh admin@server "sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys2 > /dev/null"
> ```
>
> This example shows tee being used to bypass an inherent limitation in the `sudo` command. `sudo` is unable to pipe the standard output to a file. By dumping its standard out stream into `/dev/null`, we also suppress the mirrored output in the console. The command above gives the current user root access to a server over ssh, by installing the user's public key to the server's key authorization list.

Or perhaps you want to take the output of one command, write that somewhere and also use that as input to another command?

> You can also use tee command to store the output of a command to a file and redirect the same output as an input to another command.
>
> The following command will take a backup of the crontab entries, and pass the crontab entries as an input to sed command which will do the substitution. After the substitution, it will be added as a new cron job.
>
> ```
> $ crontab -l | tee crontab-backup.txt | sed 's/old/new/' | crontab –
> ```

(credit to [Tee command usage examples](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/))

### `Tee` works with the Unix philosophy:

> Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together. Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.

(Credit to [Basics of the Unix Philosophy](https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/%7Ethenry/resources/unix_art/ch01s06.html))

`tee` fits all of these:

- it does one thing: creates an extra copy of input
- it works with other programs because it is the glue (or a 'T' plumbing piece if you prefer) that lets other programs work together as in the examples above
- it does this by manipulating a text stream given on standard input

Comment: @Joe: `sudo tee -a` is probably a more recent innovation (I first saw it in Ubuntu guides / wikis especially for setting stuff in `/proc/sys`, because switching to Ubuntu was when I switched to a `sudo` based system (how Ubuntu is configured by default) instead of using `su` with a root password).  I think `tee` predates `sudo`, so it's not a reason for `tee` existing.  You don't need `tee` for that, it's simply shorter to type interactively than `sudo sh -c 'cat > output'`.

Comment: With modern shells like bash, you can `tee` to feed two pipelines, like `foo | tee >(pipe2) | pipe1`.  Or another fun one is `ffmpeg ... |& tee /dev/tty | sed 's/.*\r// > encode.log` to see status-line updates interactively on the tty, while removing "lines" that end with carriage-return instead of newline for actual logging.  (i.e. filter out the status-line updates).  In general, you can stick a `tee /dev/tty` anywhere in a pipeline as a debug-print.

Comment: It's less a limitation of sudo you're working around and more a limitation of the shell's interpretation of >.  When you run a command with sudo its stdout gets sent back to your shell program and further redirects with > are run with the shell's permissions. If you want to write with elevated permissions you need to have the elevated part of the pipeline be what does the writing. There are a large number of ways to do this depending on precisely what effect you're going for. If you really want to use > something like 'sudo bash -c "command > outfile" ' will do the job.

Comment: Exactly, @Perkins. The shell parses the `>` and sets up the redirection before sudo even get `exec`'d, so it's _definitely_ not a limitation of sudo that it doesn't handle things it never sees. :)  I usually try to refer to this as "the sudo workflow" or some similar term when I'm explaining it, rather than describing sudo itself.

Comment: `sudo tee -a` is IMHO an abuse of tee. Use `sudo cat`, `sudo dd` or (with best performance in many cases) `sudo buffer` if you don't need the multiple outputs.

Answer (score 72):

> It's practically the same and it takes less keyboard hits to type out.

It is not the same at all...

The following appear to be somewhat equivalent, but they're not:

```
$ echo "hi" > test.txt
```

```
$ echo "hi" | tee test.txt
hi
```

The critical difference is that the former has written the data only to the named file, while the latter has written `hi` to the terminal (`stdout`) ***and*** the named file, as shown below:

[image: redirect vs tee]

---

`tee` allows you to write the data to a file *and* use it in an onward pipeline, allowing you to do useful things - like keeping data from partway through a pipeline:

```
grep '^look ' interesting_file.txt \
  | tee interesting_lines.txt \
  | sort
```

Or, you can write to a file with elevated privileges, without giving the whole pipeline elevated privileges (here `echo` and the shell are running as the user, while `tee` writes to the file as `root`):

```
echo 0 \
  | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

With `tee`, you can write to many files (*and* `stdout`):

```
echo "hi" \
  | tee a.txt b.txt
```

It's also possible to use `exec` with `tee` to record all of a script's output to a file, while still allowing an observer (`stdout`) to see the data:

```
exec > >( tee output.log )
```

Comment: Not to forget `exec > >(tee "$LOGFILE") 2>&1` in a bash script which lets the script output stdout and stderr to both, stdout and the file pointed to by `$LOGFILE`.

Comment: @rexkogitans 2>&1 isn't that cmd batch syntax?

Comment: @dmb: It's shell syntax for "send stderr(=2) to the same place as stdout(=1)"

Comment: @rexkogitans It was a fair question really, I can't really know that you haven't used "Windoze" for a decade. I use `2>&1` to drop output and err to txt files in windows.

Comment: @dmb I am sorry for sounding rude. It's all about psmears' comment. Obviously, Windows adopted Unix-style here.

Comment: You should really edit your diagrams so that command is below, `tee` above and the two outputs on either side, like a T...

Comment: Technically the data is written to STDOUT (filehandle 1) in both cases.  It's just that in the case of the redirect, `echo`'s STDOUT is connected to a file by the shell, while in the case of the pipeline, `tee`'s STDOUT is connected to the terminal.  This is a good answer on a technical site, so reasonable me defers to pedantic me. ;)

Answer (score 29):

This is a tee:
[image]

A T-shaped pipe fitting. It has an inlet, and two separate outlets.
In other words, it splits one pipe into two; like a fork in the road.

Similarly, `tee` is a pipe (`|`) that allows you to redirect your standard input to two separate outputs.

---

**Example**
Say for instance, you type `ls /`.
You'll get an output that looks something like:

```
Applications    Network     Users       bin        dev      net      private    tmp         var
Library         System      Volumes     cores      etc      home     opt        sbin        usr
```

Redirect the output to a text file, `ls / > ls.txt`, and no output is displayed in the shell, only in the resulting text file.

Want to see the output, AND pass it to a text file at the same time?
Add a `tee` to your pipe (`|`) ie: `ls / | tee ls.txt`

---

Compare the two:

```
ls /          >          ls.txt
ls /        | tee        ls.txt
```

Comment: +1 for picture which as we know is worth a thousand words

Comment: If you had picked a garden hosepipe T piece, you would have been in line with Doug McIlroy's original metaphor.

Comment: @JdeBP Sorry, I have no idea who that is. Is he the original author of the utility or something? The flow of data & physical electrical current are often compared to hydraulic systems, but you probably know that. Anyway, I just chose this style to keep it super simple. I was actually going to do that to keep it familiar, but the garden variety tend to have more of a Y-shape and/or visually complicated attachments for attaching accessories, etc. It's essentially the same though.

Comment: M. Douglas McIlroy, author of [this famous memo](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/mdmpipe.html) who [worked at Bell Labs](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/belllabs-microsite-unixhistory/streams.html) and [persuaded Ken Thompson to put pipes into Unix](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/belllabs-microsite-unixhistory/sohedid.html).

Answer (score 18):

No. You happen to mention one of the few examples where you could indeed redirect to the file using `>` and `>>` operators.

But Tee can do much more. Because you pipe to it, you can then pipe to something else.

A good example is listed on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)):

```
find "4DOS" wikipedia.txt | tee 4DOS.txt | sort > 4DOSsorted.txt
```

Basically, you can pipe to Tee, so you can then pipe from Tee to something else. If all you want to do is write a log file, yes, then you don't really need Tee.

Answer (score 18):

`tee` is far from useless. I use it all the time and am glad it exists. It's a very useful tool if you have a pipeline that you want to split up. A very simple example is that you have some directory `$d` that you want to tar and you also want to hash it because you're paranoid (like I am) and don't trust the storage medium to hold the data reliably. You *could* write it to the disk first and then hash it, but that'd fail if the archive gets corrupted before it's hashed. Furthermore, you'd have to read it and if you work on files that are several hundred GB in size a lot, you will know that you really don't want to read them again if it doesn't have to be.

So what I do is simply this:

```
tar -c "$d" | tee >(sha256sum) >(cat > "$d"".tar") > /dev/null
```

It creates the tar ball and pipes it to tee which then pipes it to two sub-shells, in one of which it's hashed and in the other of which it's written to the disk.

It's also great if you want to perform several operations on a big file:

```
< file.tar.gz tee >(sha256sum) >(tar -xz) /other/storage/location/file.tar.gz > /dev/null
```

Reads the file once, hashes it (so you can check whether it's still as it should be), extracts it, and copies it to a different location. No need to read it three times for that.

Comment: Nitpick: `tee` does not create the subshells; the calling shell runs `sha5sum` and `cat` and connects their output to file descriptors which are passed to `tee`. Also, a useless use of `cat`; you can use input redirection to have `tee` read directly from `file.tar.gz`.

Comment: @chepner You're right about the first interjection but you're completely wrong about the second one. I like writing my pipelines in order, so denoting the input at the right is terrible for readability and doing so is clearly objectively inferior to my method and totally not a subjective preference of mine. `cat` is love. `cat` is life.

Comment: You can also write `< file.tar.gz tee >(sha256sum) ...` if you are concerned about the lexical ordering of the redirections. That doesn't change the fact that there is no need for an entirely separate process just to feed a single file to `tee`.

Comment: @chepner Cool, thank you! Learned something today. :)

Comment: Useless use of `dd` as well.  Use `/other/storage/location/file.tar.gz` as an arg to `tee`, so it writes to the file directly instead of to a pipe to another process.  Same problem with the first example: you're gaining no readability at all by piping the output through `cat > "$d".tar`.  Wait, you actually have the quotes on the `".tar"` but the expansion of `$d` is unquoted?!?)

Comment: @chepner, you just changed my life forever :O

Comment: @PeterCordes, the `cat`s may be gratuitous, but `dd` will report transfer  statistics to STDERR upon receiving SIGUSR1 (useful if the job takes longer than expected). Or, replace either with `pv` to report transfer statistics to STDERR at the end.

Comment: @david Yes. You can also pass `status=progress` do `dd` to get progress information. Of course using you're launching another process and the command gets a bit longer. But it doesn't get much more complicated and I think with `cat` it's easier to comprehend. Furthermore, what does another process cost, exactly? I don't see why that'd be a criterion.

Comment: The cost of *starting* `cat` is relatively low.  The cost of an extra 100 GiB of write + read system calls definitely wastes extra CPU time and memory bandwidth for your proposed example of a huge file.  Remember that memory bandwidth is a shared resource across all cores, not to mention the extra pollution of L3 cache from that copying.  On an x86 with Spectre + Meltdown mitigation enabled, system calls are more expensive than they used to be. You're using up a measurable amount of extra CPU time over the course of that copy.  Also `>(cat > foo)` is not easier to understand than `foo`, IMO.

Comment: @david: you can see file-descriptor positions from outside a process on Linux, using `/proc/PID/fdinfo/3`.  You can attach `pv` to an already-running process to monitor it, instead of piping data *through* `pv`, using `pv -d 1234:3` (PID:FD).   http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html.  So you don't need to slow down your system with extra memory copying just in case it you end up wanting to monitor it.

Comment: That tar command should probably include `-f -`.  If that argument isn't specified, tar will use an environment variable (`$TAPE`) if present, and will then use a compiled-in default which is not defined in the man page and not necessarily a standard.

Comment: @dannysauer The man page of `tar` I have does specify it. In the "environment" section, `TAPE` is described as: "Device or file to use for the archive if --file is not specified. If this environment variable is unset, use stdin or stdout instead." I'm not sure whether this is really unspecified anywhere. I think you can be pretty sure that that environment variable isn't set.

Comment: Weird - my man page says "Otherwise, tar will assume the compiled-in default.  The default value can be inspected either using the --show-defaults option, or at  the  end  of the tar --help output."  Either way, in my "25 years of Unix sysadmin hair-pulling-out" opinion, those four extra characters are a way better use of my time than eventually spending half a day tracking down why the script doesn't work due to an environment variable on that one machine ol' Larry screwed up five years ago by copying some half-baked shell excerpt from a forum into /etc/profile. :D

Answer (score 12):

Nitpick on @bertieb's answer that says *This example shows tee being used to bypass an inherent limitation in the sudo command. sudo is unable to pipe the standard output to a file.*

There is no inherent limitation, only a misunderstanding of how the command is processed.

Example:

`sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

The **current shell** parses the command line. It finds the output redirection and performs that. Then it executes the command, which is the `sudo` and provides the remaining command line as arguments to the executed command. If the current shell does not have root permissions, then the output redirection will fail.

`echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

This works because the output redirection is deferred to the `tee` command, which at that point does have root permissions because it was executed via `sudo`.

`sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`

This works because the shell doing the redirection has root permissions.

Comment: Also, you might need `sudo` for the command, but not for the file being output and the redirection works just fine: `sudo foo-needs-privilege > /tmp/this-output-file-doesnt`

Answer (score 10):

As other people have mentioned, piping output to the `tee` command writes that output to both a file and to stdout.

I often use `tee` when I want to capture output from a command that takes a long time to run, while also wanting to visually inspect the output as the command makes it available.  That way, I don't have to wait for the command to finish running before I inspect the output.

What doesn't seem to have been mentioned yet (unless I missed it), is that the `tee` command can also write to multiple files at once.  For example:

```
ls *.png | tee a.txt b.txt
```

will write out all the `*.png` files in the current directory to two different files (`a.txt` and `b.txt`) at once.

In fact, you can type text to several different files at once with `tee` like this:

```
$ tee --append a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
These lines are appended to four different files,
and are also written to stdout.
CTRL-D
```

Answer (score 9):

The most common use of tee is to see the text on the terminal at the same time you send it to the file (or files). The wording of your question assumes you only ever write text to logfiles. I have scripts which write lists of filenames or directory names to trigger files (to be processed by other scripts asynchronously) and I use tee to send the same content to stdout. All stdout is directed to the logs. So I have my text where I want it and I have a log entry recording that I did this, all from a single 'echo' statement

tee is also the best method in Unix for making multiple identical files. I use it occasionally for making multiple empty files, like this ...

```
:|tee file01 file02 file03
```

Comment: why not `touch`? (more immediately obvious what is happening)

Comment: @Attie `touch` will not truncate files if they already exist but only update their timestamps and leave their content as is; but `tee` will truncate them. Also, doing `rm`+`touch` is different than `tee` (think about hardlinks and symlinks)

Comment: Then why not `truncate -s 0`? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine, you want to write the output of a command to a log file *AND* print to stdout. When you need to do it at the same time, then you need `tee`.

A use case is to have build scripts that write the whole build to stdout (e.g. for Jenkins) but important stuff at the same time to a separate log file (for summary emails).

You'll really start missing `tee` when you have to script in Windows. There is no `tee` and that is really annoying.

Comment: Isn't it trivial to create?

Comment: It is not possible with batch/cmd as you can not split a stream of output from a command easily.

Comment: Right but like a three-line C++ program...

Comment: The Windows unxutils distribution has many Unix command line tools which, unlike some distributions, do not pollute your Windows execution environment.  The biggest limitation is on "glob"bing, which works differently on Unix/Linux than on Windows.  "tee" is among the tools available.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm pretty sure most of the Unix command-line utilities started as three-line C programs. It was one of the main design philosophies on Unix, after all - tiny tools that do *one* job and communicate well with others.

Comment: Don't be silly, it's 2018. Use Powershell, it has `tee`. Cmd was never intended for serious scripting - that's what VBS was for. Powershell is the new go-to scripting tool. Granted, Cmd is still pretty powerful, but the command-line tools are pretty few.

Comment: @Luaan Well, exactly! Hence porting that philosophy into your Windows dev environment when needed seems like a no-brainer