# How can I split output in more than 3 parallel processes in bash?

Tags: bash

How can I split `stdout` to several parallel processes in one reading step?  `grep`/`sed` is only  an example

```
file AAA
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

```
cmd1 ($ cat AAA ) -----+---- cmd2 ( eg. grep "A" > fileA.txt ) ----->>
                       |
                       +---- cmd3 ( eg. sed -n -e '/^A/,/^D/p' > fileB.txt--->>
                       |
                       +---- cmd4 ( eg. grep "C" > fileC.txt ) ---->>
                       |
                       +---- cmd5 ( eg. grep "F" > fileF.txt ) ---->>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of 'tee'?](https://superuser.com/questions/1356841/what-is-the-purpose-of-tee)

Comment: In your case, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1356926/432690) especially.

Comment: cat AAA | tee >( grep DD > DDD.txt) >( grep AA > AAA.txt) >( grep FF > FFF.txt) >( grep BB > BBB.txt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759394/how-to-fork-pipe-stdin-in-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

paf1's comment is the minimal solution.

This is longer, but it gives you the control of GNU Parallel:

```
cat AAA |
  parallel --pipe --tee ::: 'grep "A" > fileA.txt' "sed -n -e '/^A/,/^D/p' > fileB.txt" 'grep "C" > fileC.txt' 'grep "F" > fileF.txt'
```

So you could do something like:

```
cat AAA |
  parallel --pipe --tee grep {} '>' file{}.txt ::: A B C D E
```

or:

```
cat AAA |
  parallel --pipe --tee --tag grep {} ::: A B C D E
```

If you are running a lot more than 3 receivers of the input, then this is often easier to read.